# Scroll в RichTextBox и LinkLabel

Tags: c#, winforms

Вывожу в RichTextBox список LinkLabel-ов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Всё норм! 
Но если в папке много файлов то получается так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То что не влезло в экран не видно и не как не добраться.
Если сделать на весь экран, ссылок станет больше. Но опять же, если они не помещаются в экран, их не видно и добраться до них, ни как нельзя.

Пробовал так:

```
// Метод для вывода ссылок
private void ListOpenFoldersFile(List<LinkLabel> listLinked)
        {
            InfoWindowRich.Controls.Clear();
            foreach (var item in listLinked)
            {
                item.Click += LinkedLabelClicked;
                InfoWindowRich.Controls.Add(item);

                // Скролл
                InfoWindowRich.SelectionStart = item.Text.Length;
                InfoWindowRich.ScrollToCaret();
            }
        }

// Формирование ссылок
public void CreateLinkLabel(string pathFolder, List<LinkLabel> listLinkedLabelFile, string selectedExtension)
        {
            string[] inf = Directory.GetFiles(pathFolder, $"*{selectedExtension}", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

            for (var i = 0; i < inf.Length; i++)
            {
                listLinkedLabelFile.Add(new LinkLabel()
                {
                    Text = inf[i],
                    Location = new Point(0, i * 20),
                    AutoSize = true,
                    Font = new Font("Segoe UI", 13), //Segoe UI Semibold; 11,25pt; style=Bold
                    VisitedLinkColor = Color.FromArgb(52, 73, 94),
                    LinkColor = Color.FromArgb(51, 51, 51), // 255, 215, 71 yellow rgb(52, 152, 219) url
                    ActiveLinkColor = Color.FromArgb(52, 73, 94),
                    LinkBehavior = LinkBehavior.NeverUnderline,
                    Name = inf[i],
                    Links =
                    {
                        new LinkLabel.Link()
                        {
                            Name = inf[i]
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

// При нажатии на ссылку
private void LinkedLabelClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var linkLabel = sender as LinkLabel;
            if (linkLabel == null)
                return;
            linkLabel.LinkVisited = true;
            Process.Start(linkLabel.Links[0].Name);
        }
```

Так же пробовал включать разные настройки в дизайнере, не чего не помогло.
Как можно решить данную проблему? Может кто сталкивался?

Я предполагаю, что ссылки выводятся в окно RichTextBox, но находятся по верх элемента RichTextBox. По этому и настройки не применяться. Но как решить не пойму.

Comment: `MultiLine = true`?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ  да, `MultiLine = true`.

Comment: у вас в последнем фрагменте с кодом 2скрол бара, там в свойствах такие же включить можно

Comment: @AntonNikolaev `InfoWindowRich.SelectionStart = item.Text.Length; InfoWindowRich.ScrollToCaret(); }` это вот это имелось ввиду?  Без них тоже не работает. И в настройках я тоже всё пробовал ставить. Результат тот же .

Comment: попробуйте вот это `richTextBox1.ScrollBars = RichTextBoxScrollBars.Both; `

Comment: @OXYGEN Результат тот же. То есть, полоски скролла с верху и снизу то появляется но не активные. Как будто в элементе RichTextBox не чего нет.

Comment: EugeneTM попробуйте тогда использовать Listbox в место  richTextBox

Comment: @OXYGEN Нет ListBox не сработал :( , а вот Panel сработал!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего RichTextBox и ListBox не предназначены для таких целей.Так как, они видимо могут определять только текстовую информацию, а я передaвал объекты LinkLabel.
Проблему решил с помощью Panel. Заменил RichTextBox на Panel
`InfoWindowRich.Controls.Add(item);` на `panel1.Controls.Add(item);` и в свойствах включил AutoScroll.